# multicolumn design problem

Tags: two-column, book-design

I tried to use multiple approaches to obtain the following general template with multicolumn, however, one problem that I come across is that the fontsizes changes; is there any take on how to beautify the general outline ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The look of the titles could be obtained with `sectsty` or `titlesec` packages. Without these packages is possible defining something as:

```
\def\RULE{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.5ex}}
\newcommand{\tmpsection}[1]{}
\let\tmpsection=\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\vspace{4ex}\protect{\RULE}\vspace{-5ex}\begin{center}\tmpsection{#1}\end{center}\vspace{-4ex}\RULE\nobreak\vspace{3ex}}
```

For the main text you only need  `\raggedright` and the usual formating commands for bold, italics, etc.

For the first contact information, surely many  ways are possible. My attempt is simplify the typing text and format commands in the contents using the macro \ContacUs that  need 9 arguments. This change font formats when needed, add the last sentence indented in both margins (using  a `quoting` environment) and finally add two rules, without any tabular environment.

If most items of a subsection are fixed, you can do the same for other parts. For example with macro `\RATINGS`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}% 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}% dummy text
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=5pt}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow} 
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
%\usepackage{tgchorus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{aurical}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{2ex}{2pt}{-1ex}{2pt}%
\sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.4ex}\MakeUppercase}

\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}

\newcommand\ContactUs[9]{
{\small\sffamily 
#1\\% Address
\textbf{Phone:} #2~~$\bullet$~~%
\textbf{Financial Aid Phone}: #3\\ 
\textbf{Email:} #4 \\   
\textbf{Fax:} #5~~$\bullet$~~\textbf{CEEB Code:} #6 \\
\textbf{Website:} \url{#7}~~$\bullet$~~%
\textbf{ATC Code:} #8}
\begin{quoting}
\footnotesize\Fontskrivan%\calligra ... what you want
#9  
\end{quoting}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\color{gray}
\offinterlineskip
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.2ex}\vspace{.5mm}
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.4ex}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-5ex}
}

\newcommand\RATINGS[3]{%
{\footnotesize\sffamily%
\textbf{Admission Selectiviy Ratings:} #1\hfill%
\textbf{Fire Safety Rating:} #2\hfill% 
\textbf{Green Rating:} #3}
}

% End of preamble ===========================
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\section*{Abilene Christian University}
\ContactUs
{ACU Box 27940, Abilene, TX, 79699-9141.}
{325-674-2300}{325-674-2300}
{info@admissions.acu.edu}
{325-674-2130}{6001}
{www.acu.edu}{4050}
{This private school, affiliated with the Chruch of Christ
Church, was founded in 1906. It has a 208--acre campus}
\subsection*{RATINGS}
\RATINGS{80}{74}{76}
\subsection*{STUDENS AND FACULTY}
\textbf{Lore impsum:} Lore ipsum. 
\textbf{Lore impsum with emphasis:}
\textit{Lore ipsum dolor sit amet}. 
\textbf{More text:} \lipsum[3]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[5]
\section*{Nobody knows University}
\ContactUs
{ACU Box 0000, Nowere, Nocountry, PO Box 0000.}
{555-555-5550}{555-555-5551}
{nodisturb@wearesleeping.edu}
{555-555-5552}{0000}
{www.noboyknow.edu}{4050}
{This the finest personal campus, were I am  
completely relaxed.}
\subsection*{RATINGS}
\RATINGS{0}{0}{10000}
\subsection*{STUDENS AND FACULTY}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{material}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection*{Methods}
\lipsum[3] 
\section*{Results}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Discussion}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: cheers. as u can see each after each \section{} u have a mini tabular version which i don't know how to implement within the two column design. do u see that after each \section{} u have a tabular section with a one line mini header followed by a 3 row 2 column and end header \bottomrule section ?

Comment: @PeterHorsch A tabular environment is not needed fot this, but I will explain with an example.

Comment: thank you very much. It's a bit confusing to a novice for me. I like the sectsty package but i just cannot see how to implement the mini tabular version that is followed after each \section{hello} which includes a mini header, along with other details that is in \textbf{xxx}: ... and then a mini end header ... along with a \bottomrule.

Comment: @PeterHorsch, Answer updated.